# Search a dataframe column in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Dataframes like the following:

df1:

```
   foo
0    2
1   11
2   18
3    6
4   14
5   12
6    8
7   13
8    7
9    5
```

df2:

```
   bar   date
0    2   06-01-2020
1    5   06-01-2020
2    7   06-01-2020
3    8   06-01-2020
4    3   06-01-2020
```

I want to search the values of `foo` in `bar` and if there is a match then update it in another column in `df1`

Expected output:

```
   foo result   date
0    2   True   06-01-2020
1   11  False   24-08-2020
2   18  False   24-08-2020
3    6  False   24-08-2020
4   14  False   24-08-2020
5   12  False   24-08-2020
6    8   True   06-01-2020
7   13  False   24-08-2020
8    7   True   06-01-2020
9    5   True   06-01-2020
```

I tried this but it didn't do the trick

```
result = []
for i in df1['foo']:
    for j in df2['bar']:
        if i==j:
            result.append('True')
        else:
            result.append('False')
```

How to look for a value in a column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dataframe is known for this kind of transformation.

The one-liner is

```
df1['result'] = df1.foo.isin(df2.bar)
```

> Edit for new question:

```
refdict=dict(list(zip(df2.bar, df2.date)))
df1.date=df1.foo.apply(lambda x: refdict.get(x, todaysdate))
```

Comment: Mark the answer accepted and close the question if it worked.

Comment: I tried replacing the TRUE and FALSE but getting the error: `Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=bool)' and 'str'`

This is what I did: `allot_df['Kit Status'].replace(to_replace=dict(TRUE="Return", FALSE="Onsite"), inplace=True)`

Comment: allot_df['Kit Status'].replace(to_replace={True:"Return", False:"Onsite"}, inplace=True)

Comment: Hi, Can I get the date in df1 like if the value is `True` then `df1['date']` contains date of `df2['date']` else today's date ?

Comment: I have update the question's `df2` and `expected output`.. I'll try to explain better.

If an item of `foo` is in `bar` then `df1['date']` should have the value of `df2` date column else it should have today's date in the column

Comment: I tried this `df2['date'].loc[df1.foo.isin(df2.bar)]` but it just fill the single top column